# storing a database connection string into my.settings in a .net DLL data layer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dll, data-access-layer, strongly-typed-dataset

Hy everybody
I've always used this approach while implementing data layer DLL for web application:

1) put datasets into the dll project
2) use a helper class with a method like this:

```
public shared sub settCnnStr(strconnhere as string)
My.Settings.Item("connectionString") = strconnhere
end sub
```

3) when I need to use the dll I call a method like this (usually into global.asax):

```
xxxxxxx.helper.setCnnStr("yyyyyyyyyyyyyy")
```

This method always worked for me nicely but I'd like to know if this method could have serious drawback or if there's a better solution.

thanks

Pierluigi

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any serious drawbacks with this approach.

However slightly better solution could be to **specify the connection string in the configuration file** and read it directly from your Class Library project through the [My.Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) object.

### How to read connection string settings with My.Setting

1) Add a connection string setting in the [Visual Studio Settings Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25zf0ze8.aspx) in your Class Library project. This will add it to the `App.config` configuration file for the project and generate a custom [My.Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class.

2) Since Class Library projects cannot read from `App.config` files, you'll have to move the generated connection string setting to your `Web.config` file:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ClassLibrary.My.MySettings.MyConnString"
             connectionString="SomeConnString" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

3) This allows you to easily retrieve the connection string from your Class Library project this way:

```
Dim connString = My.Settings.MyConnString
```

**Related resources:**

- [How to Add or Remove Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25zf0ze8.aspx)
- [Using My.Settings in Visual Basic 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379611%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#vbmysettings_topic3)

Comment: This is a nice solution but usually the DLL connection string depends on which user login on the web application.
So I prefer to have the connection string setted dinamically after user login

Comment: Are your users logging in with a Windows account? In that case you could connect to the database with the identity of the authenticated user [using Windows Authentication, Integrated Security and Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647396.aspx#paght000008_trustedsubsystems). In that case the connection string won't contain any login credentials and is therefore static.